# Nondegeneracy of duality pairing

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I wish to ask two related questions.

Given a vector space of possibly infinite dimension, consider a subspace of its algebraic dual. The following statement  seems plausible to me but I am unable to prove it:

If the intersection of kernels of all linear forms in this subspace contains only the zero element of the original vector space, then this subspace of linear forms is in fact the entire algebraic dual.

I think the converse of the above claim follows from the non-degeneracy of the bilinear pairing between a vector space and its dual. Namely, the only element in the original vector space that is annihilated by all linear forms is the zero vector.

In relation to this bilinear form between a vector space and its algebraic dual, here is my other question:

Is the non-degeneracy of the bilinear form for duality pairing an independent premise or it comes as a consequence of how the dual space is constructed?

Thank you.

Comment: You write "Given a vector space".  If you really meant "Given a finite-dimensional vector space" then add that extra detail to your question.  Since there is only one notion of dual space in the finite-dimensional case, it was unclear why you specify *algebraic* dual (what else could it be?) and that's why I wrote this comment.

Comment: I am considering a general vector space that is not necessarily finite-dimensional. I am not interested in topological dual here, so I used "algebraic" dual.

Comment: Then for clarity, please emphasize at the start of the question that you are considering a possibly infinite-dimensional vector space to explain why you use the term "algebraic dual".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is always positive when the vector space is finite dimensional (as perhaps you already knew) and always *negative* when the vector space is infinite-dimensional.

Let $F$ be a field, $V$ be an $F$-vector space, and $V^*$ be the algebraic dual space.  If $U$ is a subspace of $V^*$ such that
the only $v \in V$ satisfying $\varphi(v) = 0$ for all $\varphi \in U$ is $v = 0$, you want to know if $U$ must be $V^*$.

Case 1: $\dim_F V$ is finite.

We can assume $V \not= \{0\}$.
The dual space $V^*$ has the same finite dimension as $V$. Set $d = \dim_FU$, which is finite and necessarily positive since $V \not= \{0\}$. Let $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_d$ be a basis of $U$. Then the linear mapping $V \to F^d$ by $v \mapsto (\varphi_i(v))_{i=1}^d$ is injective by the defining assumption about $U$, so
$$
\dim_F(V) \leq d = \dim_F(U) \leq \dim_F(V^*) = \dim_F(V),
$$
which implies $\dim_F(U) = \dim_F(V) = \dim_F(V^*)$, so $U = V^*$ by comparing the finite dimensions.

Case 2: $\dim_F V$ is infinite.

Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an algebraic basis of $V$, and for
each $i_0 \in I$ let $\varphi_{i_0} \in V^*$ be the $e_{i_0}$-coefficient function for this basis:
$\varphi_{i_0}(\sum x_ie_i) = x_{i_0}$. These functionals $\varphi_i$ in $V^*$ are linearly independent.

Let $U$ in $V^*$ be the $F$-span (finite linear combinations) of the functionals $\varphi_i$, so $\dim_F(U) = {\rm card}(I) = \dim_F(V)$.
For $v = \sum_{i \in I} x_ie_i$ (finitely many nonzero coefficients), if $\varphi(v) = 0$ for all $\varphi \in U$ then $x_i= 0$ for all $i \in I$, so $v = 0$.  Thus $U$ has the property you want.

However, $U$ is *not* all of $V^*$ because $\dim_F U = \dim_F V$ and it be shown when $\dim_F V$ is infinite that $\dim_F V < \dim_F V^*$! I first learned this from the MO page [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13322/slick-proof-a-vector-space-has-the-same-dimension-as-its-dual-if-and-only-if-i) and later wrote up an account of the argument myself [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/dualspaceinfinite.pdf).

Concerning your second question, the non-degeneracy of the pairing between an $F$-vector space $V$ and its algebraic dual space $V^*$ is provable due to how the dual space is defined (it is all linear maps $V \to F$). That is definitely not a hypothesis.

If $\varphi \in V^*$ is not $0$ then trivially there is some $v \in V$ such that $\varphi(v) \not= 0$ in $F$.

If $v \in V$ is not $0$ then to show there is $\varphi \in V^*$ such that $\varphi(v) \not= 0$ we use a basis of $V$ (in the algebraic sense: Hamel basis, finite linear combinations). Letting $\{e_i\}$ be a basis of $V$, so $v = \sum c_ie_i$ (finitely many nonzero coefficients $c_i$), some $c_{i_0}$ is not $0$, so the functional $\varphi(\sum x_ie_i) = x_{i_0}$ is in $V^*$ and $\varphi(v) = c_{i_0} \not= 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! It seems that finite-dimensional methods (e.g. using dual bases) can be pushed to the infinite-dimensional setting up to a point where the algebraic dimension of the vector space becomes strictly less than that of the dual. I must admit that I have not entirely understood the proof in your pdf file. Modulo this fact, though, everything else is very clear. I really appreciate it that you took the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Why are you trying to use an algebraic dual space in the infinite-dimensional setting?

Comment: Oh, I was actually working with topological duals but suddenly realized that I had never understood these properties even in the algebraic sense. Now I have learned  that the algebraic situation is more intricate than what a dense subset or closed range in topological vector spaces entails.

Comment: I wouldn't say the algebraic setting is more intricate, just different.  In particular, when using dual spaces in the infinite-dimensional setting there is nearly always a topology put on the space and you work with the continuous dual space.